# LibGDX Java set velocity at an angle

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have a problem with setting the velocity for a Body object at a certain angle (I want the body to move in a straight line at a given speed at a certain angle). The Body#setLinearVelocity method requires the X and Y directions. I don't know how to get these values from an angle (form -180 to 180 degrees). I will be grateful for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert an angle to coordinates (of length 1) you can use this:

```
// angle needs to be in radians. If it's in degrees multiply it by Math.PI / 180f
angle = angleDegree * Math.PI / 180f;
x = Math.cos(angle);
y = Math.sin(angle);
```

Then add these parameters to the `setLinearVelocity` method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It works! Thanks.
I have an additional question. How to use it when changing body position? I want to set the body position by some distance (e.g. 100) in the indicated direction based on the given angle.

Comment: Multiply the values `x` and `y` with the distance (e.g. 100) and set the position of your object to it's current position with an added x and y. Something like this: `object.setPosition(object.position.x + x, object.position.y + y)`. But note that if you set the object's position like this, it will not collide with other objects in your Box2D world, because it's position was 'set' and it wasn't realy 'moved'.